# Disable copy paste on text field odoo 13

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I have a text field.

```
my_field = fields.Text()
```

I want to disable copying and paste(ctrl+c, ctrl+v) from intput with java script or python. How i can do it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the `FieldText` [widget](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#widgets) and prevent `copy` and `paste` [events](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#event-system). Create a new widget and bind the events then set the `widget` attribute on the text field.

***Example:*** ( The module name is `stack_overflow` )

```js
odoo.define('stack_overflow.actions', function (require) {
"use strict";

   var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');
   var registry = require('web.field_registry');

   var no_copy_paste = basic_fields.FieldText.extend({

        events: _.extend({}, basic_fields.FieldText.prototype.events, {
            'copy': '_onCopyPaste',
            'paste': '_onCopyPaste',
        }),

        _onCopyPaste: function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            alert("Copy/Paste Disabled!");
        },
   });

   registry.add('no_copy_paste', no_copy_paste);
});
```

Add the js file to an [asset bundle](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#assets-management):

```xml
<template id="assets_backend" name="stack_overflow assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/stack_overflow/static/src/js/actions.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Set the widget attribute on the text field:

```xml
<field name="description" widget="no_copy_paste" placeholder="Add a description..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the copy-paste on the text field using jquery by attaching event handlers `copy` & `paste`. here is the sample.

```
 $('.field_text').on("copy paste",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```