# How to restrict user to copy and paste the text in a field i created?

Tags: xml, odoo

I created the field for user to enter a text. But I don't want the user to copy the content somewhere and paste it into the field I created.

In py:

```py
class classname(models.Model):
    _inherit='sale.order'
    field_name = fields.Char('Field Name')
```

In xml:

```xml
<record id = "id_name" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">sale.order.inherit</field>
<field name ="model">sale.order</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
<field name ="arch" type ="xml" >
<xpath expr="//field[@name='existfield_id']" position ="after" >
<field name ="field_name" />
</xpath>
</field>
</record>
```

Could anyone help me in this?

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567846/disable-copy-paste-on-text-field-odoo-13

Comment: Thanks @ himanshu but it is in javascript. Is there any possible to do it by defining function in py?

Comment: I don't think so, you have to use JS in order to achieve the same.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and thank you for your time @himanshu